# Incrementing elements in a list for a given variable range

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given that a list, has `N` elements. Suppose `i` represents the `i`th element of `list_1` with all elements initially 0. Also there is a list:

`a = [ 1 , 2 , 3, 4, ., . , N]`

I need to increment elements in `list_1` by 1, which are in the range `[x-y , x+y]` inclusive, where `y` is the `i`th element of list `a`.

I tried list comprehension, but could not come up with a possible way of doing it. I am new to python so I couldn't think about any other possible way!

> Sample Input:

`list_1 = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

> Sample Output:

`list_1 = [5, 5, 4, 4, 3]`

Example: The problem asks to increment elements that fall in the given range i.e. say `x-y= 0` and `x+y = 4` , it means increment `0th`, `1st`, `2nd` , `3rd` and `4th` element of the list.

I would like to know a way to get the desired list, and overcoming the errors.

Comment: List comprehensions apply to the whole list (though they _could_ be used for a slice). I'd suggest a normal for loop. (If you want though, I could show both ways.)

Comment: Oh also, there _is_ a 0th index, it's the first item. Python starts with 0 as an index so that if you have a list as such: `numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, `numbers[0]` gives you `1`, `numbers[1]` gives `2`, and so on. (Negative indices start from the back, so that `numbers[-1]` is `5`, `numbers[-2]` is `4`, and so on.)

Comment: I agree, there is a 0th index and it corresponds to the 1st element. But there is no 0th element. The problem asks to increment elements that fall in the given range i.e. say `x-y= 0 ` and `x+y = 4` , it means increment `0` th, `1`st, `2`nd , `3`rd and `4`th element of the list.

Comment: I guess if it falls outside, it can just be ignored as I don't thing we can just randomly add more elements if there aren't enough.

Comment: I'll pop up an answer and see if it's good.

Comment: Did you try solving this yourself?

Comment: Nvm, Stardust got there first lol.

Comment: Please show some sample inputs and expected outputs, as well as the *code* of any attempts you've made.

Comment: Do you want to modify the original list, or create a copy?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Modify the original list, for each new value sets of x and y.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Updated the question with sample input and output.

Comment: Could you correct `x = list_1.index(i) + 1` and the statements "For `x-y= 0` there exist no zeroth element." and "For `x+y > len(list_1)` there again exists no element"? I just want to make sure that we are on the same page with regards to what you want vs. what is available to you.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't understand what's wrong with `x = list_1.index(i) + 1`? The type of x is `int` and it conveniently shows which element we are concerned about for a given set of range.

Comment: Are you adding +1 for a reason other than one-based indexing assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. This will increment in the range of *indices* `x-y` to `x+y`.

```
list_1 = list(range(10))

def incList(ls, x, y):
    return [e + 1 if x-y <= i <= x+y else e for i, e in enumerate(ls)]

print(incList(list_1, x=3, y=2))
print(incList(list_1, x=3, y=4))
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9]
```

You can use `enumerate` to check the index and manipulate the element value in a single list comprehension.

Alternatively, if you want to iterate from the `x-y`th *element* to the `x+y`th *element*, use `x-y-1 <= i <= x+y-1` in the list comprehension instead.

---

#### EDIT:

The original question suggested that a copy of the list with incremented values is fine, but the comments suggest otherwise. In order to change the original list directly, we can make a small alteration to the function.

```
def incList(ls, x, y):
    for i in range(max(0, x-y), min(len(ls), x+y+1)):
        ls[i] += 1
```

As before, change `x-y` and `x+y+1` to `x-y-1` and `x+y` if desired.

Comment: You could reverse the condition to be `e + 1 if x-y >= i > x+y else e`

Comment: @GeeTransit You're right, something like that makes more sense. I'll edit the answer now.

Comment: Whoops, my condition wasn't right. Looks like you fixed it tho so :)

Comment: For x = 3, y= 2; the list should increment 1st to 5th elements, not 1st to 5th indices.

Comment: @DivxBargali In that case, change it to `x-y-1 <= i <= x+y-1` and it should work the way you intend.

Comment: @StardustGogeta Thank you. I'll try that.

Comment: This creates a copy, rather than modifying the original list.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It does. I was under the impression that was fine because the question mentioned trying list generators, which will always copy the list. I see that they said otherwise in the comments, so I'll edit in a version that modifies the list. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You should probably add `max` and `min` to the first part as well. +1

Comment: @StardustGogeta I looked up for `enumerate` function and understood how it works. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @StardustGogeta For higher values of N this seems to be taking a lot of time. Is there any way of optimising it?

Comment: @DivxBargali Unfortunately, if you do, in fact, need to obtain the entire list after the increment, then I suspect there are no fundamental optimizations that can be made. The program visits each location in the range exactly once, making it an O(n) algorithm with the list comprehension and an O(2y) => O(y) algorithm with the loop, and I suspect that y is typically linearly related to n. On the other hand, if you are interested in the value of only one or a few values after several increments, you don't need to traverse large portions of the list and can indeed make it more efficient.